# Getting illegal_argument_exception error in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running the following POST query with elastic search head and for some reason I am getting a error in the response window as follows :

Request :-

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "state": "jakarta"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "country_name": "indonesia"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "status": true
          }
        },
        {
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "master_sort": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Error:-

```
    {
      "error": {
      "root_cause": [
        {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "query malformed, empty clause found at [1:495]"
        }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "query malformed, empty clause found at [1:495]"
    },
    "status": 400
    }
```

Please suggest that how to handle this type of errors. Currently I am using 6.8 version of elastic-search. And I am implementing this in my Rails application.

Comment: please share the post request that you have executed.

Answer (score 0):

the error message says that you have an empty clause in your query, start by removing that one, it's in your filter context:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "state": "jakarta"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "country_name": "indonesia"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "status": true
          }
        },
        {<=======//to remove
        }<=======//to remove
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "master_sort": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```